# .htaccess RewriteEngine with with various query strings

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, random

I have a site which can be open with multible get Resquests and without one.

So there is

> ?group=x , ?id=x, ?ha=x

All of them can be used at the same time, or only 1 or 2 of them.

I want to rewrite my http://www.example.com/test.php?.... 
to http://www.example.com/example

**EXAMPLE:**

So when i open *www.example.com/test.php?group=x&id=y* 
 it should be displayed as *www.example.com/example*

And when i open *www.example.com/test.php?ha=z* 
it should also display *www.example.com/example*

Is this possible with the mod_rewirte?

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting a rule in your .htaccess file like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^test.php.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^test.php.*$ example [L]
</IfModule>
```

It should only apply to requests that start with `/test.php` and redirect all of them to `http://wwww.yoursite.com/example` .

You are going to lose your query string parameters with this method, unless you pass them using [clean URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL), which you have to configure with htaccess as well.